# How to create "System.Linq.Expression" expression dynamically with parentheses

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, expression

I have a need to create expressions dynamically. My question is How to add parentheses in System.Linq.Expression to handle precedence...

`int a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, d = 2;`

I have converted below expression

```
 var v = a > 1 || b > 1 && c > 1 || d > 1;
 Expression case1Expr =

                Expression.AndAlso(
                Expression.OrElse(
                Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "a"), Expression.Constant(1)),
                Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "b"), Expression.Constant(1))),


                Expression.OrElse(
                Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "c"), Expression.Constant(1)),
                Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "d"), Expression.Constant(1))));
```

But how to convert one with parentheses,

```
var v2 = (a > 1 || b > 1) && (c > 1 || d > 1);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I may be missing your question but wouldn't you just do:

```
Expression first = Expression.OrElse(
    Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "a"), Expression.Constant(1)),
    Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "b"), Expression.Constant(1)));

Expression second = Expression.OrElse(
    Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "c"), Expression.Constant(1)),
    Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "d"), Expression.Constant(1)));

Expression final = Expression.AndAlso(first, second);
```

Results in: `(((a > 1) OrElse (b > 1)) AndAlso ((c > 1) OrElse (d > 1)))`

Comment: That's exactly what the OP is already doing; there's no real need to put the values in named variables.

Comment: After asking question I also realized that, trying it out

Comment: @Servy Agreed. I was just breaking it out for clarity. Milan, you may want to delete the question as you already had the solution! :)

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand a bit on the other answers; parentheses are what we need to keep the *infix* notation we use to describe equations (A OP B) from being ambiguous. Other notations, such as *postfix* (A B OP), don't need it.

In your case, you're putting together an expression tree, which is also unambiguous, i.e. there is only one way of interpreting it. So there is no concept of parentheses in an expression tree. The "shape" of the tree is what determines the order of operations.

Answer (score 1):

You specify precedence by how you construct your expression tree. The `&&` operator normally has precedence over the `||` operator, so your conversion would apply to the expression with parentheses. Otherwise it would just be:

```
var v = a > 1 || b > 1 && c > 1 || d > 1;

OrElse(
    GreaterThan(a > 1),

    OrElse(
      AndAlso(
        GreaterThan(b > 1),
        GreaterThan(c > 1)),
      GreaterThan(d > 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have already has those semantics.  When you call `ToString` on the exact code that you have you get this:

```
(((a > 1) OrElse (b > 1)) AndAlso ((c > 1) OrElse (d > 1)))
```

There is no need for a specific expression to represent parenthesis; the parenthesis are implicit in the way that you compose the expressions.  In your code you pass the `Or` expressions to the `And` expressions, so the `Or` expressions will be parenthesized.